# Deep Link-Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, deep-linking, deeplink

I need the deep link of Tableau Mobile App. Example:- For miscrostrategy, the deep link is "mstr://",on hyperlinking this URI, microstrategy mobile application is opened. Need to perform the same operation for Tableau.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are deep links for Tableau using tableau:// but they aren't documented (yet).  You could try sending yourself alert/emails/subscriptions to your mobile device and deconstruct what is provided.